# How can i create animations in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i do animations in react? Is there any useful package for this? Should i create a custom hook and make a script? I want to do an animated text and also a canvas to display a color as the mouse moves around.

This is my content

```
Main.js:

import React from 'react'
import Heading from '../organisms/Heading'
import Button from '../atoms/Button'
import './Main.css'

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <div className='main_container'>
        <section className="main" id="main">
        <div className="content">
            <h2>Hello, I´m <br/> <span>Mateo Ghidini</span></h2>
            <div className="animated-text">
                <h3>Web Designer</h3>
                <h3>Jr Full-stack Web Developer</h3>
            </div>
            <Button className="btn" content="See My Work"/>
            <div className="media-icons">
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mghidini/"><i className="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                <a href="https://github.com/mateoghidini1998"><i className="fab fa-github"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Main
```

Answer (score 1):

1. [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations). This way is the best for a simple animation. When you use it instead of importing javascript micro libraries, your bundle is smaller.
2. [ReactTransitionGroup](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group). This module has been developed by the guys from ReactJs community. Developers describe this library as:

“A set of components for managing component states (including mounting and unmounting) over time, specifically designed with animation in mind.”